# using lookup table to fill multiple columns

Tags: r, lookup

I have nine different dataframes that I want to run the same lookup test on.

Here are two of the nine dataframes...

```
PIRO_PLS_Points <- structure(list(SPECIES1 = c("CE", "BE", "BE", "YB", "BF", "BE", 
"SU", "CE", "SU", "SU"), ComName1 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Latin1 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    TSN1 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), SPECIES2 = c("CE", "BE", "BE", 
    "YB", "BF", "BE", "BE", "SU", "SU", "SU"), ComName2 = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), Latin2 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), TSN2 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), SPECIES3 = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), ComName3 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), Latin3 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), TSN3 = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_)), data_types = c("N", "N", "F", "F", "N", 
"N", "N", "F", "F", "C", "C", "N", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"N", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "N", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "N", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "N", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "N", "C", "N", 
"N", "N", "C", "N", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"N", "N", "C", "F", "F", "F", "F", "N", "N", "F", "F", "N", "N", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "F", "F", "C"), .Names = c("SPECIES1", "ComName1", 
"Latin1", "TSN1", "SPECIES2", "ComName2", "Latin2", "TSN2", "SPECIES3", 
"ComName3", "Latin3", "TSN3"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
```

and

```
SLBE_PLS_Points <- structure(list(SPECIES1 = c("CE", "BE", "BE", "YB", "BF", "BE", 
"SU", "CE", "SU", "SU"), ComName1 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Latin1 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    TSN1 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), SPECIES2 = c("CE", "BE", "BE", 
    "YB", "BF", "BE", "BE", "SU", "SU", "SU"), ComName2 = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), Latin2 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), TSN2 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), SPECIES3 = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), ComName3 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), Latin3 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), TSN3 = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_)), data_types = c("N", "N", "F", "F", "N", 
"N", "N", "F", "F", "C", "C", "N", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"N", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "N", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "N", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "N", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "N", "C", "N", 
"N", "N", "C", "N", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"N", "N", "C", "F", "F", "F", "F", "N", "N", "F", "F", "N", "N", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "F", "F", "C"), .Names = c("SPECIES1", "ComName1", 
"Latin1", "TSN1", "SPECIES2", "ComName2", "Latin2", "TSN2", "SPECIES3", 
"ComName3", "Latin3", "TSN3"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
```

The dataframes already contain the columns I want to fill (`ComName1`,`Latin1`,`TSN1`,`ComName2`, etc.) based upon another column; `SPECIES1`, `SPECIES2`, etc.

Here is the lookup table that I would like to apply...

```
sp.list <-c('BE','YB','SU')
com.list <-c('bear','yellow','supper')
latin.list <- c('juglans','quercus','fraxinus')
tsn.list <- c(100203,999999,88888)

lookup = cbind(sp.list,com.list,latin.list,tsn.list)
```

And looks like:

```
     sp.list com.list latin.list tsn.list
[1,] "BE"    "bear"   "juglans"  "100203"
[2,] "YB"    "yellow" "quercus"  "999999"
[3,] "SU"    "supper" "fraxinus" "88888"
```

So, in the end I would like to populate `$ComName1`, `$Latin1`, `$TSN1`, `$ComName2`, etc. all based up on the `lookup` table. I thought the lookup table would be the simplest way, but I'm open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing to do is stack all your data frames, then merge on the lookup table

```
dfs <- rbind(PIRO_PLS_Points, SLBE_PLS_Points, ...)
dfs$sp.list <- dfs$SPECIES1
merged <- merge(dfs, lookup)
```

You can split it back in to separate data frames using `split()` or subsetting.

Comment: This only provides a lookup for SPECIES1. I would like to use the same lookup to go through and fill in ComName2, Latin2, TSN2, ComName3, etc.

Comment: You can run it three times, eg make `merged_species1`, `merged_species2`, etc then `cbind()` them all into a single dataset. But you would probably be better off using SQL at that point.